# Building email tracking for open rate and geo analytics with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, meteor

As a project, I want to learn how to create an email tracker that generates a unique pixel, tracks open rates in JavaScript (MeteorJS).

Does anyone have any resources I can look into to accomplish this? I know ToutApp does this in PHP and found similar tutorials in PHP but nothing in JS.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use Iron:Router's [server-side routing](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#server-routing) to track when a user clicks on something like `/emails/ew45gf23`. The ID in the URL could be the `_id` from the collection that stores all the emails sent, e.g. `EmailsSent.findOne({_id: _id})`

```
Router.route('/emails/:_id', function () {

  var emailClicked = EmailsSent.findOne({_id: _id});

  ... do whatever you need to with the tracking ...

  this.response.end('email click received\n');

}, {where: 'server'});
```